# MySQL select between two ISO-formatted dates

Tags: mysql, date

I want to select all rows in a mysql table that have their date between to given dates. The format in my database is e.g.

```
"2018-09-28T12:00:00".
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value AS field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value, n.nid AS nid, n.title AS title
FROM 
{node} n
LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_datum_der_veranstaltung} d ON d.entity_id = n.nid
WHERE (d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value BETWEEN '2018-01-01T00:00:00' AND '2018-01-30T23:59:00') 
ORDER BY d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value ASC
```

Please note, this the query generated by the Drupal API, which is working (in case you wonder about the `{node}`)

Now, as the dates in the DB are strings, how can I compare the values?

Comment: What's` field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value ` type?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to get DateTime

```
SELECT d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value AS field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value, n.nid AS nid, n.title AS title
FROM 
{node} n
LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_datum_der_veranstaltung} d ON d.entity_id = n.nid
WHERE (d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value
 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d')  AND  STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-30T23:59:00', '%Y-%m-%d') ) 
ORDER BY d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value ASC
```

Or you can use [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function `CAST(d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value AS DATETIME)` to datetime.

```
SELECT d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value AS field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value, n.nid AS nid, n.title AS title
FROM 
{node} n
LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_datum_der_veranstaltung} d ON d.entity_id = n.nid
WHERE (CAST(d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value AS DATETIME)
 BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01T00:00:00' AS DATETIME)  AND  CAST('2018-01-30T23:59:00' AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY d.field_datum_der_veranstaltung_value ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/52842)

Answer (score 0):

here is example of iso `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')` frmated date,try like below

```
SELECT * from table_name
FROM table_name 
where datecondition>=DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
and datecondition <=DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-30T23:59:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
```